# How to pass Variable to script task SSIS, Visual Studio 2010, c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, variables, ssis, parameter-passing

I'm trying to find the way how I can pass the server name as a variable to script task within SSIS solution. I'm using VS 2010 and c#.

Within my SSIS I have Name (string) variable defined and I added this variable as ReadOnlyVariable within my Script task.

c# code looks like this:

[image]

Problem starts (I guess) when I'm trying to pass the local ServerName to the OleDbDataAdapter which works perfectly with strConn, but doesn't work with my ServerName variable.

I have tried to pass it in a form "User::Name" but it didn't work.

Any suggestion would be appreciated :)

Best

Comment: You can do the same using veritable and changing property EvaluateAsexpression.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you comment, but unfortunately it tells me nothing - could you explain it a bit more, or show some examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to write exactly this code? *(I assume that you have variable **Name** defined as string)*. And you can also parameterize your DB name as well.

```
string strConn = Dts.Connections[Dts.Variables["Name"].Value + "\\MY_DB_NAME"].ConnectionString;
```

UPDATE:
If you would like to connect to your DB via script task, the best practise is to configure new connection manager (see the picture) [image]. The most important is the name of your connection (in my case "MY_NEW_CM")

If you have your Server name or DB name saved inside a variable, you can use expression editor inside the connection manager properties (see the picture) [image]

Later you can use this configured connection in the code inside Script task as follows:

```
ConnectionManager cm = Dts.Connections["MY_NEW_CM"];
```

I assume that you would like to use this connection manager to run some SQL command.

You can make it like that:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlConn;
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand sqlComm;
ConnectionManager cm = Dts.Connections["MY_NEW_CM"];

// Request an open connection
sqlConn = (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)cm.AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction);

// Do your work
sqlComm = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("UPDATE YourTable SET YourColumn = 'SomeValue'", sqlConn);
int rowsAffected = sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Thanks for your input - it occurred that there were some problem with \\. Right now I'm wondering how pass the connection to db that I have defined within connection manager instead of passing db in variables. I was trying to use several methods but none worked. Any clues?

Comment: I made an update of my previous answer... I hope it will help you. :)